# Boot Linux off a BitLocker protected drive

Tags: linux, encryption, bitlocker, clonezilla, luks

I have a bootable USB drive with Clonezilla installed, which I use to take images of drives from various computers. **Is there a way to install BitLocker on it, so that during boot I get prompted for a BitLocker password, and after that it boots Clonezilla**?

I suppose I'm after a bootable drive with whole-disk encryption which can easily be opened in Windows without installing any special software whatsoever (though portable software that doesn't require admin rights would be acceptable).

Comment: Is there a purpose for this exercise? A bootable Clonezilla USB is not a desktop OS, it's just a bare minimum to boot and run the Clonezilla tool, it has no personal data.

Comment: Thanks Changan, are you suggested having Clonezilla on an unencrypted partition, and the captured images on another (encrypted) partition?

Comment: If want something that works under both Linux and Windows, probably neither LUKS nor BitLocker is what you are looking for. (VeraCrypt or something like that, maybe?)

Comment: Bitlocker is only a good choice if you use it with TPM protection for the system disk. If you want to encrypt a removable disk (respectively a disk that is accessed from multiple OS) better use VeraCrypt.

Comment: Hi Robert, I used BitLocker on a removable disk and was able to open it fine on another computer.

Answer (score 1):

To encrypt images made with Clonezilla, you can encrypt them File-Based with eCryptFS: [Documentation](https://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/01_Save_disk_image)

I don't think it is possible for Clonezilla to write to a BitLocker encrypted partition or even boot from one. If you want Full-Disk-Encryption, its probably the easier way to install a small Linux on your drive (like Alpine) and copy disks from there (using dd or partImage or something similar). You can even install [Partclone](https://partclone.org/), which is the software running on Clonezilla Live systems.